# presentViewController after dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to present a view controller (`SLServiceTypeFacebook`) after I dismiss a view controller. Like this

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    ////////////////////////////////////
    //Some Stuff Other Calculations//
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //Then

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        // Facebook Service Type is Available

        SLComposeViewController *slVC   =   [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler handler    =   ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
        {
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Done");
            }

            [slVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:Nil];
        };
        slVC.completionHandler = handler;
        [slVC setInitialText:post[@"user_fullname"]];
        [slVC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post[@"url"]]];

        [self presentViewController:slVC animated:NO completion:Nil];
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The Facebook modal automatically cancels itself.

am I doing something wrong conceptually?

Comment: Do you want to dismiss slVC view controller or self.presentingViewController ??

Comment: self.presentingViewController, and then present slVC after some other code but I dont know why SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled keeps on triggering itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a completion block like so:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

   //SHOW YOUR NEW VIEW CONTROLLER HERE!
}];
```

Your missing your completion handler above.

Comment: NSLog out each step in the completion block, that definitely works as i use it all over the place for things when using modal VC's. Something in the block is failing in this case.

Comment: Dev2rights, I am doing that already. Its printing out Cancelled. please refer to the code

Comment: Ok i see it, your calling '[slVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:Nil];' in your handler block. Remove this.

Comment: Well remove it anyway it isn't supposed to be in there. According to the docs it means that there isnt a user account available. Have you got the user to sign into facebook  ? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205

Comment: Ok then final things id say i that your not setting a valid [NSURL] for the url , it isnt just a string you add. see this post for how its used in twitter implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428304/slcomposeviewcontroller-completionhandler

Comment: You cant just remove things, you need to have some parts to make it a valid post. Refer to the docs i sent above and go through step by step to make sure you havent missed anything.

Comment: Dev2rights, I just removed the [slVC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post[@"url"]]]; and just set the initial text to @'Test', it still doesnt work

Comment: Well as mentioned you need to re read the docs and work out why its calling cancelled. Cancelled isn't just from the user pressing cancelled there is some error with logging in / having the right data for the facebook post.

Comment: Dev2rights, It works fine else in the app. Only while dismissing a view controller its having this problem

Comment: Im not ure what to say, i use the above block for showing the same controller in one of my apps and it works fine. Cant be much more help sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    NewViewController *viewController = [[NewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([NewViewController class]) bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *topRootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topRootViewController.presentedViewController)
    {
        topRootViewController = topRootViewController.presentedViewController;
    }

    [topRootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```